# Apache Solr + OpenNLP Lemmatization

Tags: solr, search-engine, nutch, opennlp, lemmatization

I'm building a search engine with Apache Nutch and Solr.

Right now I'm trying to integrate Solr with the OpenNLP lemmatization, because I want my search engine to retrieve a document that, for example, contains the word "create", even if the user searches for the word "created", or "create".

The problem I'm encountering is that the lemmatization doesn't seem to work since when I'm searching for the word "created" Solr doesn't find any result (when I search for "create" it does find).

The field type definition:

```
<fieldType name="text_lemma" class="solr.TextField"
        positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.OpenNLPTokenizerFactory"
                    sentenceModel="en-sent.bin"
                    tokenizerModel="en-token.bin"/>
            <filter class="solr.OpenNLPPOSFilterFactory" posTaggerModel="en-pos-maxent.bin"/>
            <filter class="solr.OpenNLPLemmatizerFilterFactory"
                    dictionary="en-lemmatizer.txt"/>                        
            <filter class="solr.TypeTokenFilterFactory" types="stop.pos.txt"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

The field type definition:

```
<field name="content" type="text_lemma" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
```

And also I have the following line in the schema:

```
<copyField source="content" dest="text"/>
```

In the solrconfig.xml file, I didn't change the default request handler "/select" that I'm doing the search with.

I added the following lines to the solrconfig.xml file:

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/analysis-extras/lucene-libs" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/analysis-extras/lib" regex="opennlp-.*\.jar" />
```

What do I need to change/add so the search will work properly? Do I need to modify the the request handler in the solrconfig.xml? Do you know a good example that I can try to follow (this guide didn't work for me either: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/language-analysis.html#opennlp-lemmatizer-filter)?

I would really appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: First thing, use the Solr Admin UI analysis page (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/analysis-screen.html) for understanding if (and how) your analyzers&tokenizers are working. You need to select the corresponding fieldType (`text_lemma `) and put some dummy text to test if the tokenizer&analyzer is really working. Did you reindex your data after the change to the `fieldType`?

Comment: Thank you! It really helped me to find my problem! I wasn't using the right dictionary in the solr.OpenNLPLemmatizerFilterFactory filter, so the words weren't being lemmatized to their lemmas.

Comment: Hey, I am trying to use opennlp with solr. Can you send the files en-lemmatizer.txt, stop.pos.txt? I did not get them any where. I would really appreciate if you can help me with this.