# How to use analyzers in Solr query

Tags: solr

I try to add stemming/lemmatization to Solr query but fail to understand how exactly I use those in the query.

I'm using the `manufacturers.xml` data and successfully loaded it into a core. one of the entries is:

```
  {
    "id":"adata",
    "compName_s":"A-Data Technology",
    "address_s":"46221 Landing Parkway Fremont, CA 94538",
    "_version_":1722999917838860288},
  {
```

and my query is: `land`

When analyzing the `text_en` field I can see a filter called PSF which transform the `Landing` from the input into `land`. I've also loaded lemmatization according to [this manual](https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_3/language-analysis.html#opennlp-lemmatizer-filter) and added it to a field called "text_lemma" similar to what was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51421146/apache-solr-opennlp-lemmatization). My question is how exactly do I use those filters in the query? I ran `address_s:land` and it gave no results.

Thanks

Comment: you cannot use them while quering, but you need define them in the schema.xml. In the same file you define a fieldType which has analyzers, one can be at index time and one can be at query time...

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti thx! do you have a reference for that? what should I do exactly?

Comment: please check this link https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/field-type-definitions-and-properties.html..

Comment: When you use the field type with the `_s` prefix, you query against the pure string version (i.e. no analysis etc. takes place). Instead, query against `address` - `address:land`. While I haven't looked at the default schema and examples in a while, I don't think that field is stored (since the `_s` version is already stored).